# Iterating over ArrayList in .jsp (MVC2 compliant)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, el

I'm writing a web app that uses a servlet to maintain an ArrayList of VideoData objects (these just contain basic information about movies like the title, type of movie, etc).

The servlet puts this List in the request's scope and forwards both the request and response to a jsp (only part of the servlet code is shown here):

```
public class VideoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private ArrayList<VideoData> library = new ArrayList<VideoData>();

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response) {

        try {

            // put ArrayList in Request's scope
            request.setAttribute("the_table", library);

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/listvideos.jsp").forward(request,
                    response);

            ...
```

The listvideos.jsp is shown below. I'm getting a Tomcat error stating that the uri for the JSTL cannot be resolved. I've used EL in other parts of my jsp code without having to have any special import line like this, and I'm not sure if JSTL is still the preferred way to solve this type of problem while still trying to adhere to MVC2 and keeping all the Java code in the Servlet. Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Ideally I'd like a pure EL solution, if that's possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 
'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 

<html>

    <head>

        <title>Cattle Drive Assignment Servlets-4: Videos</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Cattle Drive Assignment Servlets-4: Videos</h1>

        <form method='post' action='/videos/VideoServlet'>

            <a href="http://localhost:8080/videos/addvideo.jsp">Add a video</a>

            <br>
            <br>

            <table border="1">

                <tr>

                    <th>Title</th>

                    <th>Star</th>

                    <th>Type</th>

                    <th>VHS</th>

                    <th>DVD</th>

                    <th>Description</th>

                </tr>

                <c:forEach items="${the_table}" var="movie">

                <tr>

                    <td>${movie.getTitle()}</td>

                    <td>${movie.getStar()}</td>

                    <td>${movie.getType()}</td>

                    <td>${movie.inVHS()}</td>

                    <td>${movie.inDVD()}</td>

                    <td>${movie.getDesc()}</td>

                </tr>

                </c:forEach>

            </table>

        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks basically correct. Looks like the error you're seeing indicates that the JSTL taglibs cannot be found in the classpath. Please make sure that `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` are in your war's `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: Or when you're on Tomcat 6/7, alone jstl-1.2.jar is also enough. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info